# Highcharts Highmaps - hover / click external list and show on map

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, highmaps

I have a list of country codes on a page and want to show the country on the map based on a click of one of the country `iso-a2` items in the list.

```
$('li').click(function() {
  var ctry = $(this).text();
  $('#container').highcharts().get(ctry).setState('hover');
})

<ul>
  <li>AL</li>
  <li>AD</li>
  <li>AM</li>
</ul>
```

I have a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/tw6r0gcu/).

My map code is:

```
var chartData = [{
  "name": "Africa",
  "data": [{
    "code": "DZ"
  }, {
    "code": "AO"
  }, {
    "code": "BJ"
  }, {
    "code": "BW"
  }, {
    "code": "BF"
  }, {
    "code": "BI"
  }, {
    "code": "CM"
  }, {
    "code": "CV"
  }, {
    "code": "CF"
  }, {
    "code": "TD"
  }, {
    "code": "CD"
  }, {
    "code": "CG"
  }, {
    "code": "KM"
  }, {
    "code": "DJ"
  }, {
    "code": "EG"
  }, {
    "code": "GQ"
  }, {
    "code": "ER"
  }, {
    "code": "ET"
  }, {
    "code": "GM"
  }, {
    "code": "GA"
  }, {
    "code": "GH"
  }, {
    "code": "GN"
  }, {
    "code": "GW"
  }, {
    "code": "CI"
  }, {
    "code": "KE"
  }, {
    "code": "XK"
  }, {
    "code": "LS"
  }, {
    "code": "LR"
  }, {
    "code": "LY"
  }, {
    "code": "MG"
  }, {
    "code": "MW"
  }, {
    "code": "ML"
  }, {
    "code": "MR"
  }, {
    "code": "MU"
  }, {
    "code": "YT"
  }, {
    "code": "MA"
  }, {
    "code": "MZ"
  }, {
    "code": "NA"
  }, {
    "code": "NE"
  }, {
    "code": "NG"
  }, {
    "code": "RW"
  }, {
    "code": "ST"
  }, {
    "code": "SN"
  }, {
    "code": "SC"
  }, {
    "code": "SL"
  }, {
    "code": "SO"
  }, {
    "code": "ZA"
  }, {
    "code": "SS"
  }, {
    "code": "SD"
  }, {
    "code": "SZ"
  }, {
    "code": "TZ"
  }, {
    "code": "TG"
  }, {
    "code": "TN"
  }, {
    "code": "UG"
  }, {
    "code": "EH"
  }, {
    "code": "ZM"
  }, {
    "code": "ZW"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Asia",
  "data": [{
    "code": "AF"
  }, {
    "code": "BH"
  }, {
    "code": "BD"
  }, {
    "code": "BT"
  }, {
    "code": "BN"
  }, {
    "code": "KH"
  }, {
    "code": "CN"
  }, {
    "code": "HK"
  }, {
    "code": "IN"
  }, {
    "code": "ID"
  }, {
    "code": "IR"
  }, {
    "code": "IQ"
  }, {
    "code": "IL"
  }, {
    "code": "JP"
  }, {
    "code": "JO"
  }, {
    "code": "KZ"
  }, {
    "code": "KW"
  }, {
    "code": "KG"
  }, {
    "code": "LA"
  }, {
    "code": "LB"
  }, {
    "code": "MO"
  }, {
    "code": "MY"
  }, {
    "code": "MV"
  }, {
    "code": "MN"
  }, {
    "code": "MM"
  }, {
    "code": "NP"
  }, {
    "code": "KP"
  }, {
    "code": "OM"
  }, {
    "code": "PK"
  }, {
    "code": "PH"
  }, {
    "code": "WA"
  }, {
    "code": "SA"
  }, {
    "code": "SG"
  }, {
    "code": "KR"
  }, {
    "code": "LK"
  }, {
    "code": "SY"
  }, {
    "code": "TW"
  }, {
    "code": "TJ"
  }, {
    "code": "TH"
  }, {
    "code": "TR"
  }, {
    "code": "TM"
  }, {
    "code": "AE"
  }, {
    "code": "UZ"
  }, {
    "code": "VN"
  }, {
    "code": "PS"
  }, {
    "code": "YE"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Europe",
  "data": [{
    "code": "AL"
  }, {
    "code": "AD"
  }, {
    "code": "AM"
  }, {
    "code": "AT"
  }, {
    "code": "AZ"
  }, {
    "code": "BY"
  }, {
    "code": "BE"
  }, {
    "code": "BA"
  }, {
    "code": "BG"
  }, {
    "code": "HR"
  }, {
    "code": "CY"
  }, {
    "code": "CZ"
  }, {
    "code": "DK"
  }, {
    "code": "EE"
  }, {
    "code": "FO"
  }, {
    "code": "FI"
  }, {
    "code": "FR"
  }, {
    "code": "GE"
  }, {
    "code": "DE"
  }, {
    "code": "GR"
  }, {
    "code": "HU"
  }, {
    "code": "IS"
  }, {
    "code": "IE"
  }, {
    "code": "IM"
  }, {
    "code": "IT"
  }, {
    "code": "LV"
  }, {
    "code": "LI"
  }, {
    "code": "LT"
  }, {
    "code": "LU"
  }, {
    "code": "MK"
  }, {
    "code": "MT"
  }, {
    "code": "MD"
  }, {
    "code": "MC"
  }, {
    "code": "ME"
  }, {
    "code": "NL"
  }, {
    "code": "NO"
  }, {
    "code": "PL"
  }, {
    "code": "PT"
  }, {
    "code": "RO"
  }, {
    "code": "RU"
  }, {
    "code": "SM"
  }, {
    "code": "RS"
  }, {
    "code": "SK"
  }, {
    "code": "SI"
  }, {
    "code": "ES"
  }, {
    "code": "SE"
  }, {
    "code": "CH"
  }, {
    "code": "UA"
  }, {
    "code": "GB"
  }, {
    "code": "VA"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "North America",
  "data": [{
    "code": "AI"
  }, {
    "code": "BS"
  }, {
    "code": "BB"
  }, {
    "code": "BZ"
  }, {
    "code": "BM"
  }, {
    "code": "CA"
  }, {
    "code": "KY"
  }, {
    "code": "CR"
  }, {
    "code": "CU"
  }, {
    "code": "DM"
  }, {
    "code": "DO"
  }, {
    "code": "SV"
  }, {
    "code": "GL"
  }, {
    "code": "GD"
  }, {
    "code": "GT"
  }, {
    "code": "HT"
  }, {
    "code": "HN"
  }, {
    "code": "JM"
  }, {
    "code": "MX"
  }, {
    "code": "FM"
  }, {
    "code": "NI"
  }, {
    "code": "PA"
  }, {
    "code": "PR"
  }, {
    "code": "KN"
  }, {
    "code": "LC"
  }, {
    "code": "VC"
  }, {
    "code": "TC"
  }, {
    "code": "US"
  }, {
    "code": "VI"
  }, {
    "code": "VG"
  }, {
    "code": "TT"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "South America",
  "data": [{
    "code": "AR"
  }, {
    "code": "AW"
  }, {
    "code": "BO"
  }, {
    "code": "BR"
  }, {
    "code": "CL"
  }, {
    "code": "CO"
  }, {
    "code": "CW"
  }, {
    "code": "EC"
  }, {
    "code": "PF"
  }, {
    "code": "GF"
  }, {
    "code": "GY"
  }, {
    "code": "PY"
  }, {
    "code": "PE"
  }, {
    "code": "MF"
  }, {
    "code": "SR"
  }, {
    "code": "TT"
  }, {
    "code": "UY"
  }, {
    "code": "VE"
  }, {
    "code": "AR"
  }, {
    "code": "AW"
  }, {
    "code": "BO"
  }, {
    "code": "BR"
  }, {
    "code": "CL"
  }, {
    "code": "CO"
  }, {
    "code": "CW"
  }, {
    "code": "EC"
  }, {
    "code": "PF"
  }, {
    "code": "GF"
  }, {
    "code": "GY"
  }, {
    "code": "PY"
  }, {
    "code": "PE"
  }, {
    "code": "MF"
  }, {
    "code": "SR"
  }, {
    "code": "UY"
  }, {
    "code": "VE"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Oceania",
  "data": [{
    "code": "AS"
  }, {
    "code": "AU"
  }, {
    "code": "FJ"
  }, {
    "code": "GU"
  }, {
    "code": "KI"
  }, {
    "code": "MH"
  }, {
    "code": "NC"
  }, {
    "code": "NZ"
  }, {
    "code": "MP"
  }, {
    "code": "PW"
  }, {
    "code": "PG"
  }, {
    "code": "WS"
  }, {
    "code": "SB"
  }, {
    "code": "TP"
  }, {
    "code": "TO"
  }, {
    "code": "TV"
  }, {
    "code": "VU"
  }]
}];

// Instantiate the map
var chart = Highcharts.mapChart('container', {

  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },

  chart: {
    map: 'custom/world',
    spacingTop: 20,
    spacingBottom: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#DEEFF5'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Regions'
  },

  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },

  mapNavigation: {
    enabled: true,
    buttonOptions: {
      verticalAlign: 'bottom'
    }
  },

  plotOptions: {
    map: {
      allAreas: false,
      joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        states: {
          hover: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
          }
        },
      },
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '',
        pointFormat: '{point.name}: <b>{series.name}</b>'
      }
    }
  },

  series: chartData

});

$('li').click(function() {
  var ctry = $(this).text();
  $('#container').highcharts().get(ctry).setState('hover');
})
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saying that you want to "show" the country? Do you want to perform drilldown, zoom or just change color/state of the clicked country?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve desired effect by iterating chart series data and update matching data color

```
$('li').click(function() {
  var ctry = $(this).text();
  chart.series.map((el,i)=>{
    el.data.map((e,j)=>{
    if(e.code==ctry){
    chart.series[i].data[j].update({
        color: 'red'
      })
    }
    })
  })
})
```

```js
var chart;
var chartData = [{
  "name": "Africa",

  "data": [{
    "code": "DZ"
  }, {
    "code": "AO"
  }, {
    "code": "BJ"
  }, {
    "code": "BW"
  }, {
    "code": "BF"
  }, {
    "code": "BI"
  }, {
    "code": "CM"
  }, {
    "code": "CV"
  }, {
    "code": "CF"
  }, {
    "code": "TD"
  }, {
    "code": "CD"
  }, {
    "code": "CG"
  }, {
    "code": "KM"
  }, {
    "code": "DJ"
  }, {
    "code": "EG"
  }, {
    "code": "GQ"
  }, {
    "code": "ER"
  }, {
    "code": "ET"
  }, {
    "code": "GM"
  }, {
    "code": "GA"
  }, {
    "code": "GH"
  }, {
    "code": "GN"
  }, {
    "code": "GW"
  }, {
    "code": "CI"
  }, {
    "code": "KE"
  }, {
    "code": "XK"
  }, {
    "code": "LS"
  }, {
    "code": "LR"
  }, {
    "code": "LY"
  }, {
    "code": "MG"
  }, {
    "code": "MW"
  }, {
    "code": "ML"
  }, {
    "code": "MR"
  }, {
    "code": "MU"
  }, {
    "code": "YT"
  }, {
    "code": "MA"
  }, {
    "code": "MZ"
  }, {
    "code": "NA"
  }, {
    "code": "NE"
  }, {
    "code": "NG"
  }, {
    "code": "RW"
  }, {
    "code": "ST"
  }, {
    "code": "SN"
  }, {
    "code": "SC"
  }, {
    "code": "SL"
  }, {
    "code": "SO"
  }, {
    "code": "ZA"
  }, {
    "code": "SS"
  }, {
    "code": "SD"
  }, {
    "code": "SZ"
  }, {
    "code": "TZ"
  }, {
    "code": "TG"
  }, {
    "code": "TN"
  }, {
    "code": "UG"
  }, {
    "code": "EH"
  }, {
    "code": "ZM"
  }, {
    "code": "ZW"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Asia",
  "data": [{
    "code": "AF"
  }, {
    "code": "BH"
  }, {
    "code": "BD"
  }, {
    "code": "BT"
  }, {
    "code": "BN"
  }, {
    "code": "KH"
  }, {
    "code": "CN"
  }, {
    "code": "HK"
  }, {
    "code": "IN"
  }, {
    "code": "ID"
  }, {
    "code": "IR"
  }, {
    "code": "IQ"
  }, {
    "code": "IL"
  }, {
    "code": "JP"
  }, {
    "code": "JO"
  }, {
    "code": "KZ"
  }, {
    "code": "KW"
  }, {
    "code": "KG"
  }, {
    "code": "LA"
  }, {
    "code": "LB"
  }, {
    "code": "MO"
  }, {
    "code": "MY"
  }, {
    "code": "MV"
  }, {
    "code": "MN"
  }, {
    "code": "MM"
  }, {
    "code": "NP"
  }, {
    "code": "KP"
  }, {
    "code": "OM"
  }, {
    "code": "PK"
  }, {
    "code": "PH"
  }, {
    "code": "WA"
  }, {
    "code": "SA"
  }, {
    "code": "SG"
  }, {
    "code": "KR"
  }, {
    "code": "LK"
  }, {
    "code": "SY"
  }, {
    "code": "TW"
  }, {
    "code": "TJ"
  }, {
    "code": "TH"
  }, {
    "code": "TR"
  }, {
    "code": "TM"
  }, {
    "code": "AE"
  }, {
    "code": "UZ"
  }, {
    "code": "VN"
  }, {
    "code": "PS"
  }, {
    "code": "YE"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Europe",
  "data": [{
    "code": "AL"
  }, {
    "code": "AD"
  }, {
    "code": "AM"
  }, {
    "code": "AT"
  }, {
    "code": "AZ"
  }, {
    "code": "BY"
  }, {
    "code": "BE"
  }, {
    "code": "BA"
  }, {
    "code": "BG"
  }, {
    "code": "HR"
  }, {
    "code": "CY"
  }, {
    "code": "CZ"
  }, {
    "code": "DK"
  }, {
    "code": "EE"
  }, {
    "code": "FO"
  }, {
    "code": "FI"
  }, {
    "code": "FR"
  }, {
    "code": "GE"
  }, {
    "code": "DE"
  }, {
    "code": "GR"
  }, {
    "code": "HU"
  }, {
    "code": "IS"
  }, {
    "code": "IE"
  }, {
    "code": "IM"
  }, {
    "code": "IT"
  }, {
    "code": "LV"
  }, {
    "code": "LI"
  }, {
    "code": "LT"
  }, {
    "code": "LU"
  }, {
    "code": "MK"
  }, {
    "code": "MT"
  }, {
    "code": "MD"
  }, {
    "code": "MC"
  }, {
    "code": "ME"
  }, {
    "code": "NL"
  }, {
    "code": "NO"
  }, {
    "code": "PL"
  }, {
    "code": "PT"
  }, {
    "code": "RO"
  }, {
    "code": "RU"
  }, {
    "code": "SM"
  }, {
    "code": "RS"
  }, {
    "code": "SK"
  }, {
    "code": "SI"
  }, {
    "code": "ES"
  }, {
    "code": "SE"
  }, {
    "code": "CH"
  }, {
    "code": "UA"
  }, {
    "code": "GB"
  }, {
    "code": "VA"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "North America",
  "data": [{
    "code": "AI"
  }, {
    "code": "BS"
  }, {
    "code": "BB"
  }, {
    "code": "BZ"
  }, {
    "code": "BM"
  }, {
    "code": "CA"
  }, {
    "code": "KY"
  }, {
    "code": "CR"
  }, {
    "code": "CU"
  }, {
    "code": "DM"
  }, {
    "code": "DO"
  }, {
    "code": "SV"
  }, {
    "code": "GL"
  }, {
    "code": "GD"
  }, {
    "code": "GT"
  }, {
    "code": "HT"
  }, {
    "code": "HN"
  }, {
    "code": "JM"
  }, {
    "code": "MX"
  }, {
    "code": "FM"
  }, {
    "code": "NI"
  }, {
    "code": "PA"
  }, {
    "code": "PR"
  }, {
    "code": "KN"
  }, {
    "code": "LC"
  }, {
    "code": "VC"
  }, {
    "code": "TC"
  }, {
    "code": "US"
  }, {
    "code": "VI"
  }, {
    "code": "VG"
  }, {
    "code": "TT"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "South America",
  "data": [{
    "code": "AR"
  }, {
    "code": "AW"
  }, {
    "code": "BO"
  }, {
    "code": "BR"
  }, {
    "code": "CL"
  }, {
    "code": "CO"
  }, {
    "code": "CW"
  }, {
    "code": "EC"
  }, {
    "code": "PF"
  }, {
    "code": "GF"
  }, {
    "code": "GY"
  }, {
    "code": "PY"
  }, {
    "code": "PE"
  }, {
    "code": "MF"
  }, {
    "code": "SR"
  }, {
    "code": "TT"
  }, {
    "code": "UY"
  }, {
    "code": "VE"
  }, {
    "code": "AR"
  }, {
    "code": "AW"
  }, {
    "code": "BO"
  }, {
    "code": "BR"
  }, {
    "code": "CL"
  }, {
    "code": "CO"
  }, {
    "code": "CW"
  }, {
    "code": "EC"
  }, {
    "code": "PF"
  }, {
    "code": "GF"
  }, {
    "code": "GY"
  }, {
    "code": "PY"
  }, {
    "code": "PE"
  }, {
    "code": "MF"
  }, {
    "code": "SR"
  }, {
    "code": "UY"
  }, {
    "code": "VE"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Oceania",
  "data": [{
    "code": "AS"
  }, {
    "code": "AU"
  }, {
    "code": "FJ"
  }, {
    "code": "GU"
  }, {
    "code": "KI"
  }, {
    "code": "MH"
  }, {
    "code": "NC"
  }, {
    "code": "NZ"
  }, {
    "code": "MP"
  }, {
    "code": "PW"
  }, {
    "code": "PG"
  }, {
    "code": "WS"
  }, {
    "code": "SB"
  }, {
    "code": "TP"
  }, {
    "code": "TO"
  }, {
    "code": "TV"
  }, {
    "code": "VU"
  }]
}];

// Instantiate the map
chart = Highcharts.mapChart('container', {

  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },

  chart: {
    map: 'custom/world',
    spacingTop: 20,
    spacingBottom: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#DEEFF5'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Regions'
  },

  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },

  mapNavigation: {
    enabled: true,
    buttonOptions: {
      verticalAlign: 'bottom'
    }
  },

  plotOptions: {
    map: {
      allAreas: false,
      joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        states: {
          hover: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
          }
        },
      },
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '',
        pointFormat: '{point.name}: <b>{series.name}</b>'
      }
    }
  },

  series: chartData

});
$('li').click(function() {
  var ctry = $(this).text();
  chart.series.map((el, i) => {
    el.data.map((e, j) => {
      if (e.code == ctry) {
        chart.series[i].data[j].update({
          color: 'red'
        })
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">


<ul>
  <li>IN</li>
  <li>RU</li>
  <li>CN</li>
</ul>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="container"></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wr88uo8s/) demo

**Edit**

[Based of revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48696629/1) I think  on click you want change color plus show tooltip and on hover you want to change color of respective map.

**Note** this example activated country's color reverts back to original color when it loose focus(when country is changed)

```js
var chart;
var chartData = [{
  "name": "Africa",

  "data": [{
    "code": "DZ"
  }, {
    "code": "AO"
  }, {
    "code": "BJ"
  }, {
    "code": "BW"
  }, {
    "code": "BF"
  }, {
    "code": "BI"
  }, {
    "code": "CM"
  }, {
    "code": "CV"
  }, {
    "code": "CF"
  }, {
    "code": "TD"
  }, {
    "code": "CD"
  }, {
    "code": "CG"
  }, {
    "code": "KM"
  }, {
    "code": "DJ"
  }, {
    "code": "EG"
  }, {
    "code": "GQ"
  }, {
    "code": "ER"
  }, {
    "code": "ET"
  }, {
    "code": "GM"
  }, {
    "code": "GA"
  }, {
    "code": "GH"
  }, {
    "code": "GN"
  }, {
    "code": "GW"
  }, {
    "code": "CI"
  }, {
    "code": "KE"
  }, {
    "code": "XK"
  }, {
    "code": "LS"
  }, {
    "code": "LR"
  }, {
    "code": "LY"
  }, {
    "code": "MG"
  }, {
    "code": "MW"
  }, {
    "code": "ML"
  }, {
    "code": "MR"
  }, {
    "code": "MU"
  }, {
    "code": "YT"
  }, {
    "code": "MA"
  }, {
    "code": "MZ"
  }, {
    "code": "NA"
  }, {
    "code": "NE"
  }, {
    "code": "NG"
  }, {
    "code": "RW"
  }, {
    "code": "ST"
  }, {
    "code": "SN"
  }, {
    "code": "SC"
  }, {
    "code": "SL"
  }, {
    "code": "SO"
  }, {
    "code": "ZA"
  }, {
    "code": "SS"
  }, {
    "code": "SD"
  }, {
    "code": "SZ"
  }, {
    "code": "TZ"
  }, {
    "code": "TG"
  }, {
    "code": "TN"
  }, {
    "code": "UG"
  }, {
    "code": "EH"
  }, {
    "code": "ZM"
  }, {
    "code": "ZW"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Asia",
  "data": [{
    "code": "AF"
  }, {
    "code": "BH"
  }, {
    "code": "BD"
  }, {
    "code": "BT"
  }, {
    "code": "BN"
  }, {
    "code": "KH"
  }, {
    "code": "CN"
  }, {
    "code": "HK"
  }, {
    "code": "IN"
  }, {
    "code": "ID"
  }, {
    "code": "IR"
  }, {
    "code": "IQ"
  }, {
    "code": "IL"
  }, {
    "code": "JP"
  }, {
    "code": "JO"
  }, {
    "code": "KZ"
  }, {
    "code": "KW"
  }, {
    "code": "KG"
  }, {
    "code": "LA"
  }, {
    "code": "LB"
  }, {
    "code": "MO"
  }, {
    "code": "MY"
  }, {
    "code": "MV"
  }, {
    "code": "MN"
  }, {
    "code": "MM"
  }, {
    "code": "NP"
  }, {
    "code": "KP"
  }, {
    "code": "OM"
  }, {
    "code": "PK"
  }, {
    "code": "PH"
  }, {
    "code": "WA"
  }, {
    "code": "SA"
  }, {
    "code": "SG"
  }, {
    "code": "KR"
  }, {
    "code": "LK"
  }, {
    "code": "SY"
  }, {
    "code": "TW"
  }, {
    "code": "TJ"
  }, {
    "code": "TH"
  }, {
    "code": "TR"
  }, {
    "code": "TM"
  }, {
    "code": "AE"
  }, {
    "code": "UZ"
  }, {
    "code": "VN"
  }, {
    "code": "PS"
  }, {
    "code": "YE"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Europe",
  "data": [{
    "code": "AL"
  }, {
    "code": "AD"
  }, {
    "code": "AM"
  }, {
    "code": "AT"
  }, {
    "code": "AZ"
  }, {
    "code": "BY"
  }, {
    "code": "BE"
  }, {
    "code": "BA"
  }, {
    "code": "BG"
  }, {
    "code": "HR"
  }, {
    "code": "CY"
  }, {
    "code": "CZ"
  }, {
    "code": "DK"
  }, {
    "code": "EE"
  }, {
    "code": "FO"
  }, {
    "code": "FI"
  }, {
    "code": "FR"
  }, {
    "code": "GE"
  }, {
    "code": "DE"
  }, {
    "code": "GR"
  }, {
    "code": "HU"
  }, {
    "code": "IS"
  }, {
    "code": "IE"
  }, {
    "code": "IM"
  }, {
    "code": "IT"
  }, {
    "code": "LV"
  }, {
    "code": "LI"
  }, {
    "code": "LT"
  }, {
    "code": "LU"
  }, {
    "code": "MK"
  }, {
    "code": "MT"
  }, {
    "code": "MD"
  }, {
    "code": "MC"
  }, {
    "code": "ME"
  }, {
    "code": "NL"
  }, {
    "code": "NO"
  }, {
    "code": "PL"
  }, {
    "code": "PT"
  }, {
    "code": "RO"
  }, {
    "code": "RU"
  }, {
    "code": "SM"
  }, {
    "code": "RS"
  }, {
    "code": "SK"
  }, {
    "code": "SI"
  }, {
    "code": "ES"
  }, {
    "code": "SE"
  }, {
    "code": "CH"
  }, {
    "code": "UA"
  }, {
    "code": "GB"
  }, {
    "code": "VA"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "North America",
  "data": [{
    "code": "AI"
  }, {
    "code": "BS"
  }, {
    "code": "BB"
  }, {
    "code": "BZ"
  }, {
    "code": "BM"
  }, {
    "code": "CA"
  }, {
    "code": "KY"
  }, {
    "code": "CR"
  }, {
    "code": "CU"
  }, {
    "code": "DM"
  }, {
    "code": "DO"
  }, {
    "code": "SV"
  }, {
    "code": "GL"
  }, {
    "code": "GD"
  }, {
    "code": "GT"
  }, {
    "code": "HT"
  }, {
    "code": "HN"
  }, {
    "code": "JM"
  }, {
    "code": "MX"
  }, {
    "code": "FM"
  }, {
    "code": "NI"
  }, {
    "code": "PA"
  }, {
    "code": "PR"
  }, {
    "code": "KN"
  }, {
    "code": "LC"
  }, {
    "code": "VC"
  }, {
    "code": "TC"
  }, {
    "code": "US"
  }, {
    "code": "VI"
  }, {
    "code": "VG"
  }, {
    "code": "TT"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "South America",
  "data": [{
    "code": "AR"
  }, {
    "code": "AW"
  }, {
    "code": "BO"
  }, {
    "code": "BR"
  }, {
    "code": "CL"
  }, {
    "code": "CO"
  }, {
    "code": "CW"
  }, {
    "code": "EC"
  }, {
    "code": "PF"
  }, {
    "code": "GF"
  }, {
    "code": "GY"
  }, {
    "code": "PY"
  }, {
    "code": "PE"
  }, {
    "code": "MF"
  }, {
    "code": "SR"
  }, {
    "code": "TT"
  }, {
    "code": "UY"
  }, {
    "code": "VE"
  }, {
    "code": "AR"
  }, {
    "code": "AW"
  }, {
    "code": "BO"
  }, {
    "code": "BR"
  }, {
    "code": "CL"
  }, {
    "code": "CO"
  }, {
    "code": "CW"
  }, {
    "code": "EC"
  }, {
    "code": "PF"
  }, {
    "code": "GF"
  }, {
    "code": "GY"
  }, {
    "code": "PY"
  }, {
    "code": "PE"
  }, {
    "code": "MF"
  }, {
    "code": "SR"
  }, {
    "code": "UY"
  }, {
    "code": "VE"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Oceania",
  "data": [{
    "code": "AS"
  }, {
    "code": "AU"
  }, {
    "code": "FJ"
  }, {
    "code": "GU"
  }, {
    "code": "KI"
  }, {
    "code": "MH"
  }, {
    "code": "NC"
  }, {
    "code": "NZ"
  }, {
    "code": "MP"
  }, {
    "code": "PW"
  }, {
    "code": "PG"
  }, {
    "code": "WS"
  }, {
    "code": "SB"
  }, {
    "code": "TP"
  }, {
    "code": "TO"
  }, {
    "code": "TV"
  }, {
    "code": "VU"
  }]
}];

// Instantiate the map
chart = Highcharts.mapChart('container', {

  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },

  chart: {
    map: 'custom/world',
    spacingTop: 20,
    spacingBottom: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#DEEFF5'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Regions'
  },

  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },

  mapNavigation: {
    enabled: true,
    buttonOptions: {
      verticalAlign: 'bottom'
    }
  },

  plotOptions: {
    map: {
      allAreas: false,
      joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        states: {
          hover: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
          }
        },
      },
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '',
        pointFormat: '{point.name}: <b>{series.name}</b>'
      }
    }
  },

  series: chartData

});
$('li').click(function() {
  var ctry = $(this).text();

  chart.series.map((el, i) => {
    el.data.map((e, j) => {
      if (e.code == 'AL' || e.code == 'AD' || e.code == 'AM') {
        chart.series[i].data[j].update({
          color: '#90ed7d'
        })
      }

      if (e.code == ctry) {
        chart.series[i].data[j].update({
          color: 'red'
        })
        chart.series[i].data[j].setState('hover');
        chart.tooltip.refresh(chart.series[i].points[j]);
      }
    })
  })
})
$('li').hover(function() {
  var ctry = $(this).text();
  chart.series.map((el, i) => {
    el.data.map((e, j) => {
      if (e.code == ctry) {
        chart.series[i].data[j].update({
          color: 'red'
        })
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```css
#container {
  height: 500px;
  min-width: 310px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.loading {
  margin-top: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
}

ul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">


<ul>
  <li>AL</li>
  <li>AD</li>
  <li>AM</li>
</ul>

<div id="container"></div>
```